# About having various constructors and parameters for java

Tags: java

I have written the instructions below and till now, I've came up with having two parameters and letting the method to assign the value and retrieving it. However, one of the instruction I had to follow was to include one constructor with no parameters,  so I'm wondering what statement should I make inside the constructor without any parameters. It would be wonderful if anyone gives be a instruction. This is the code I've came up so far.

```
public class Rectangle {

    
        //first constructor no parameters 
        //public<class name> (<parameters>)<statements>}
        //two parameters one for length, one for width
        //member variables store the length and the width
        //member methods assign and retrieve the length and width 
            //returning the area and perimeter
        
        
        static int recPerimeter(int l, int w) {
            return 2*(l+w);
        }
        
        static int recArea(int l, int w) {
            return l*w;
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int p = recPerimeter(5, 3);
            System.out.println("Perimeter of the rectangle : " + p);
            
            int a = recArea(5,3);
            System.out.println("Area of the rectangle : " + a);
        }
}
```

Comment: Forget about Java and code, and decide: what rectangle should you give someone who doesn't specify anything about the rectangle they want?

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you gave us your code implementing all of the specifications in the `//` comments :)

Comment: You have no constructors for Rectangle in your code.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would take some time to read the [java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). At least the "Covering the Basics"

There is a ton wrong with your example.  You should store the the attributes of a rectangle - width and length as data members of the class which will get initialized with values through the constructors.  If a default constructor is called with no values, then set the attributes to whatever you want.  I set them to zero in the example.
Also, you need to normally create an instance of your class and then access it.  Big red flag if you are having to prepend "static" to everything.

```
public class Rectangle {

    private int recLength;
    private int recWidth;

    public Rectangle() {
        recLength = 0;
        recWidth = 0;
    }

    public Rectangle( int l, int w ) {
        recLength = l;
        recWidth = w;
    }

    public int calcPerimeter() {
        return 2*(recLength+recWidth);
    }

    public int calcArea() {
        return recLength*recWidth;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(5,3);
        System.out.println("Perimeter = "+ rec.calcPerimeter());
        System.out.println("area = " + rec.calcArea());
    }
}
```